# How to disable tab stop on a stackpanel

Tags: wpf, stackpanel, tabstop

I have a stackpanel that keeps getting focus when I tab around in the application.

Using snoop I can see that the stackpanel has a ContentControl which has a ContentPresenter. It is the ContentControl that gets the focus. How can I disable this? And why is this default behavior?

Comment: A `StackPanel` shouldn't be able to get focus unless you set `Focusable="True"` (default is `False`). Where is this `StackPanel` located, `Window`/`UserControl`, `ItemsControl`?

Comment: What happens when you set  `Focusable="False"` on the ContentControl?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is not the default behavior, if it has been overwritten by some resource then you can reset it with

```
KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
```

Or alternatively...

```
FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False"
```

Comment: What is the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False"` didn't work for me but `KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"` did

Answer (score 10):

Had a similar issue with a DataTemplate that was using a StackPanel as container.  The DataTemplate was then used for ListBox items.  None of the suggestions worked for me to prevent the items from receiving tab stops, until I used the following on the actual listbox:

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"
```

Comment: Or by code behind: `KeyboardNavigation.SetTabNavigation(control, KeyboardNavigationMode.None);`

Comment: How do you do that in UWP? Says "not supported"